# javascript setInterval() working in Dreamweaver but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dreamweaver, compatibility, setinterval

I'm trying to make an image drop up/down from a menu whenever the user clicks on the menu image which has`onClick="move()"`in the tag. So far The image starts at the top of the page, behind the menu, so it is hidden, then slides down as intended. However, after the image reaches it's stopping point, clicking the menu again does nothing at all when I test the page in both IE and Chrome. In Dreamweaver, the code executes as intended, with the ability to slide the image up after it reaches the bottom and back down again. I've tried changing the call to setInterval() because I assumed that is where the problem was but nothing seems to be working. Why does Dreamweaver execute the code properly but not Chrome or IE?

```
    var onMusic=false;
    var id;
    function move() {
        if(!onMusic) {
          moveDown()        
        }
        else {
            moveUp()
        }
    }


    function moveUp() {
        top=100
        id = setInterval(function() {
            top-=10  // update parameters 
            document.getElementById('guitar').style.top = top + 'px' // show frame
            if (top <= -500)  {// check finish condition
                onMusic=false
                clearInterval(id)
            }
         }, 10) // draw every 10ms
    }

    function moveDown() {
        var top=-500
        id = setInterval(function() {
            top+=10  // update parameters 
            document.getElementById('guitar').style.top = top + 'px' // show frame
            if (top == 100)  {// check finish condition
                onMusic=true
                clearInterval(id)
            }
        }, 10) // draw every 10ms
    }
```

Comment: 10ms is `10`, not `.1`, or?

Comment: The global window.top appears to have a meaning in chrome.. You should fix moveUp to also make it a var..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was:

```
top=100
// should be
var top = 100;
```

You can try in the console to see what I mean:

```
>top = 12 
12 
> top 
Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, Proxy: Object, external: Object…}
```

But I cleaned it up a little more in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pNh57/1/

Answer (score 3):

`id` is only visible from the scope of the `moveDown` function. Make it global so that you can call `clearInterval(id)` in `moveUp`.

Change

```
function moveDown() {
    var top=-500
    var id = setInterval(function() {
```

to

```
var id;
function moveDown() {
    var top=-500
    id = setInterval(function() {
```

And changing the dom every tenth of millisecond (`.1`) might be a little extrem...

Comment: Ok, I've taken care of that and placed `var id;` with the rest of my globals. `id` was getting declared in `moveUp()` as well so I don't think that changed anything. Still works in Dreamweaver but not in the browsers. And yeah I've had to play around with the time whenever testing as the sliding is much much slower in Dreamweaver.